# SFML 2.1 program runs fine in debug mode, but crashes in release mode

Tags: c++, qt-creator, sfml

I am using Qt Creator for an SFML project.  The problem I am currently experiencing is that my application will crash on a certain line of code *only if* I am running in release mode.

I've stripped down my application to find the exact line of code that is causing the problem.  Here is what my entire program looks like:

## Works in Debug Mode; Crashes in Release Mode

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "SFML Worked!");
    window.setVerticalSyncEnabled(true);

    sf::Shader shader;
    shader.loadFromFile("data\\shaders\\HorizontalBlur.frag", sf::Shader::Fragment);

    return 0;
}
```

If I remove the *loadFromFile* code, then it will run fine in both debug and release modes.

## Works in Debug Mode; Works in Release Mode

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "SFML Worked!");
    window.setVerticalSyncEnabled(true);

    sf::Shader shader;
    //shader.loadFromFile("data\\shaders\\HorizontalBlur.frag", sf::Shader::Fragment);

    return 0;
}
```

My system looks like this:

- Windows 8 64-bit
- Qt Creator 2.8.1
- GCC 4.8
- SFML 2.1 compiled with GCC 4.8

I'm looking for your suggestions and guidance to help me figure out what would cause this line of code to work in debug mode, but not in release mode.

Thank you!  :)

## Update #1

I am using qmake for this project.  It creates three make files:

- Makefile
- Makefile.debug
- Makefile.release

I'm not very experienced with makefiles, but I can see some information about the libraries that are being linked in the debug and release make files.

### Makefile.debug

```
LIBS        =        C:/Users/Derek/Documents/Development/Projects/Dots-A-Lot/dependencies/SFML-2.1-windows-gcc-4.8-mingw-32bits/lib/libsfml-main-d.a C:/Users/Derek/Documents/Development/Projects/Dots-A-Lot/dependencies/SFML-2.1-windows-gcc-4.8-mingw-32bits/lib/libsfml-graphics-d.a C:/Users/Derek/Documents/Development/Projects/Dots-A-Lot/dependencies/SFML-2.1-windows-gcc-4.8-mingw-32bits/lib/libsfml-window-d.a C:/Users/Derek/Documents/Development/Projects/Dots-A-Lot/dependencies/SFML-2.1-windows-gcc-4.8-mingw-32bits/lib/libsfml-system-d.a C:/Users/Derek/Documents/Development/Projects/Dots-A-Lot/dependencies/SFML-2.1-windows-gcc-4.8-mingw-32bits/lib/libsfml-audio-d.a C:/Users/Derek/Documents/Development/Projects/Dots-A-Lot/dependencies/SFML-2.1-windows-gcc-4.8-mingw-32bits/lib/libsfml-network-d.a
```

### Makefile.release

```
LIBS        =        C:/Users/Derek/Documents/Development/Projects/Dots-A-Lot/dependencies/SFML-2.1-windows-gcc-4.8-mingw-32bits/lib/libsfml-main.a C:/Users/Derek/Documents/Development/Projects/Dots-A-Lot/dependencies/SFML-2.1-windows-gcc-4.8-mingw-32bits/lib/libsfml-graphics.a C:/Users/Derek/Documents/Development/Projects/Dots-A-Lot/dependencies/SFML-2.1-windows-gcc-4.8-mingw-32bits/lib/libsfml-window.a C:/Users/Derek/Documents/Development/Projects/Dots-A-Lot/dependencies/SFML-2.1-windows-gcc-4.8-mingw-32bits/lib/libsfml-system.a C:/Users/Derek/Documents/Development/Projects/Dots-A-Lot/dependencies/SFML-2.1-windows-gcc-4.8-mingw-32bits/lib/libsfml-audio.a C:/Users/Derek/Documents/Development/Projects/Dots-A-Lot/dependencies/SFML-2.1-windows-gcc-4.8-mingw-32bits/lib/libsfml-network.a
```

I also have the debug DLLs in the debug output folder (next to the debug executable) and the release DLLs in the release output folder (next to the release executable).  The data folder is in both debug and release folders as well so that it has access to the fragment shader file.

Comment: What is the folder the program is running in? If your program is running in the executable folder and the shader exists in the Debug mode, but not in Release mode, that would explain your problem.

Comment: @luiscubal I thought that might be the problem as well.  I have the data folder and the release DLLs in the correct spot for the executable.  I can even go into that folder and run the release executable, yet it will still crash.

When I run the debug executable from its location (with the data folder and the debug DLLS), it will run normally.

Comment: Are you linking against the correct versions? Debug libraries and DLLs for debug versions, Release libraries and DLLs for release versions.

Comment: @luiscubal I took a moment to look through my qmake .pro file as well as the generated makefiles.  I think things are linking correctly, but is there a way I could verify what is being linked during the build?  I've updated my question with some more information about the makefiles.  Thank you!  :)

Comment: I notice you aren't creating a window/context. Does that help? I mean, maybe the shader isn't properly creating the OpenGL context in Release mode?

Comment: @luiscubal Good point.  Just to make sure that wasn't the issue, I re-added the code to create the window.  Unfortunately, the same thing happens.  This will run in debug mode (and open the window), but it will crash in release mode (after the window is open).  I've updated the code in my question to reflect what I just tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem.  I had followed these instructions to build SFML:

http://sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.1/compile-with-cmake.php

I had downloaded g++ 4.8.1 with mingw and used that to compile SFML.  However, when I used the .a/.dll files produced by that build, my release build would crash on that line of code.

Today (10-7-2013) I found these instructions:

https://github.com/LaurentGomila/SFML/wiki/Tutorial%3A-Compile-and-Link-SFML-with-Qt-Creator#step-10

I ran through those instructions and used the g++ 4.8.0 compiler that came with Qt Creator (instead of the one I had downloaded).  Now I am able to run in release mode without crashing.

I didn't realize that I was using one version of the compiler to build SFML (g++ 4.8.1) and another to build my application (g++ 4.8.0).

Thank you, luiscubal, for pointing me in the right direction by asking me questions about the linker.  :)